# How to sync web client and database ? Creating entity on client side and dealing with IDs

Tags: database, redux, synchronization

**Background**

Let's say I'm trying to keep a large list of items, with a web UI offering the possibility to add new ones.
My architecture is a web UI (React/Redux) + a database/server (Graph.cool).

Now when I add a new item, what I can do is simply run the "create" query, get back the item with its database ID, and store the item in an object that indexes all the items by ID.

Problem: the network might be slow / offline, the request can fail, and I'd still want to be able to immediately show the user his newly created item in the list, and sync with the database later.

**Question**

I'd need a solution that allows me to create the item locally first, and later replace the local ID with the database ID when the response comes back.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Turns out it was a problem of code organization / Redux that I had. See my answer below. Now my question doesn't quite feel as clear/useful as I intended, should I delete it ? (or improve it somehow ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create some sort of `localKey` field on the object, and add it to your store as per usual.

Whenever the backend finishes processing it and the event comes in, instead of adding the new object to the store, use the `localKey` to find the local copy, and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem of code organization / Redux that I had.

I couldn't figure out how to implement some kind of solution like Tobe O suggested, because :

- If I fired the request first I had no way to attach the localID and get it back with the response to track it
- If I created the local item first in a reducer I couldn't pass the localID to the part that does the request and stores the item extracted from the response / I think It's bad practice to throw actions from a reducer

What I did instead that seems to work well, is:

- fire a first action that gets picked up by a worker in the background
- the worker creates the localID and passes it to two new actions: one for creating the local item and one for firing the request to the database

Here's my solution in code, with Redux + Sagas + Kea + a classic todo list example:

```
export default kea({
  path: () => ["kea", "taskStore"],
  actions: () => ({
    addTask: title => ({ title }),
    storeLocalTask: (localId, title) => ({ localId, title }),
    storeDBTask: (localId, task) => ({ localId, task }),
    setTasks: tasks => ({ tasks }),
    fetchTasks: () => ({})
  }),
  *start() {
    const { fetchTasks } = this.actions;
    yield put(fetchTasks());
  },
  reducers: ({ actions }) => ({
    indexedTasks: [
      {},
      PropTypes.object,
      {
        [actions.setTasks]: (state, payload) => indexById(payload.tasks),
        [actions.storeLocalTask]: (state, payload) => {
          const { localId, title } = payload;
          return { ...state, [localId]: { localId, title } };
        },
        [actions.storeDBTask]: (state, payload) => {
          const { localId, task } = payload;
          const { [localId]: _dispose_, ...rest } = state;
          return { ...rest, [task.id]: task };
        }
      }
    ]
  }),
  takeLatest: ({ actions, workers }) => ({
    [actions.fetchTasks]: workers.fetchTasks,
    [actions.addTask]: workers.createTask
  }),
  workers: {
    *fetchTasks() {
      const res = yield db.query({
        query: gql`
          query {
            allTasks {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        `
      });
      const { setTasks } = this.actions;
      yield put(setTasks(res.data.allTasks));
      yield delay(1000);
    },
    *createTask(action) {
      const { storeLocalTask, storeDBTask } = this.actions;
      const { title } = action.payload;
      const localId = randomString();
      yield put(storeLocalTask(localId, title));

      const res = yield db.mutate({
        mutation: gql`
          mutation($title: String!) {
            createTask(title: $title) {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        `,
        variables: { ...action.payload }
      });
      yield put(storeDBTask(localId, res.data.createTask));
      yield delay(1000);
    }
  }
});
```